# Script not working as expected when run as a cronjob

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

To begin, here is an example of a filename for a daily backup file:

```
website-db-backup06-June-2020.tar.gz
```

The script below works fine when run manually via the terminal. However, I am getting this cron daemon message on my email when the script is run via cron:

```
tar: website-db-backup*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Here is a script I made to compress all daily backups every week:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Weekly compression for database backups
BACKUP_PATH=~/backup/web/database
BACKUP_FILE_DATE=`date '+%d-%B-%Y'`
tar -czf $BACKUP_PATH/website-db-weekly-compress$BACKUP_FILE_DATE.tar.gz \
    -C $BACKUP_PATH/ website-db-backup* && rm $BACKUP_PATH/website-db-backup*
```

Since the daily backup has `date` on the filename, I have to use `*` on the script. Can this be the reason?

Comment: If it is a `root` cronjob it will expand `~` to `/root`

Comment: @danielleontiev That is not the problem here but nonetheless a good hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the current working directory of the script. `website-db-backup*` does not have a path so it is executed in the current directory. You must add something like this to your script:

```
SOURCE_DIR_PATH='/path/to/backup_source'
cd "$SOURCE_DIR_PATH" || exit 1
```

In addition you should check whether there are any matching files at all before you exeute `tar`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
set -- website-db-backup*
test $# -eq 0 && { echo 'ERROR: No matching files; aborting'; exit 1; }
```

It may not be a problem in this case but as danielleontiev points out in the comment it is dangerous to use `~` in a script if this script may be executed by different users. I suggest you replace it with the intended path.

Comment: How many times does cron have to send an email when errors like this occur? I received 65 emails with the same message. Although this is run by a superuser, yes, I will stop using ~/ from now on.

Comment: @Joey I would expect one such email per script run. What is your `crontab` entry?

Comment: * 02 * * 1 path-to-scripts.sh. I wanted it to run every 2: AM on Monday. Now I changed it to 01 02 * * 1 path-to-scripts.sh.

Comment: `:` might be a better alternative than `set --` in which it doesn't clobber `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Comment: @Joey Your crontab `* 2 * * 1` will run for **every minute** of 2 AM on Monday, so 60 times in that hour. `0 2 * * 1` is what you probably want.

Comment: @iBug And what are you going to do with `:`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Since you're only interested in the expansion result (success / failed), `:` is a perfect option.

Comment: @iBug But pathname expansion does not generate an exit code. If you have an idea that works then I need example code to understand it.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I mistook it for `shopt -s failglob`.

Comment: This answer works perfectly for me. But now there is a suggestion coming from @iBug - Any examples on how to implement this? Or I can just stick to this solution.

Comment: @Joey Hold a sec, I'm going to wrap my suggestion in another answer.

Comment: @Joey There are several ways for checking the existance of matches. Doesn't matter much which one you use.

Answer (score 1):

Using `failglob` is another option, where a glob expansion failure will cause the whole command to fail (nothing is executed at all). Combined with the shell's no-op operator `:` (colon), this is a perfect way to test for glob results (success or not).

```bsh
shopt -s failglob
: website-db-backup*

# The following code is purely indicative
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Success, website-db-backup* exists"
else
  echo "Failed, nothing matches website-db-backup*"
fi
```

This has the advantage over [Hauke Laging's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591483/script-not-working-as-expected-when-run-as-a-cronjob/591486#591486) in that **it doesn't clobber existing positional parameters (`$1` etc.)**, although you can work around that by using a function:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

argc() {
  return $#
}
argc website-db-backup*

# Now check $? the same way as above
# $1, $2, ... remain untouched
```

A Bash array is also a good option:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob
FILES=(website-db-backup*)
echo "${#FILES[@]}"  # gives number of matched files
```

This is IMO the simplest and the most elegant solution.

Comment: But in order to avoid the `bash` error message you have to do it as `(: website-db-backup*) 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @HaukeLaging It must have slipped through my mind that  `${#ARRAY[@]}` is the perfect tool for this job.